# How to break out of time.Sleep

Tags: go

I just started picking up Golang a couple days ago and I can't seem to figure out to break out of time.Sleep()...

I can return / break out of the for loop, but the function wont return since Sleep continues doing its thing.

I am guessing the solution is pretty simple, but I can't seem to find the answer.

```
func main() {
  ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 1)

  go func() {
    for i := range ticker.C {
      fmt.Println("tick", i)
      ticker.Stop()
      break
    }
  }()
  time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
      ticker.Stop()

  fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to send the main goroutine a message telling it your other goroutine is complete. For that, channels are the best way to go.

```
func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)

    go func() {
        for i := range ticker.C {
            fmt.Println("tick", i)
            ticker.Stop()
            break
        }

        done <- true
    }()

    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second/2)
    select {
    case <-done:
        timer.Stop()
    case <-timer.C:
        ticker.Stop()
    }

    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Working example at http://play.golang.org/p/5NFsvC5f7P

When the timer is greater than ticker, it ticks. When it is less than, all you see is "done".

Comment: I ended up solving it by adding a channel just like the example you gave.  Then I simply did a :  if ! <- finished; sleep...; else return;

Comment: @davissp14, a loop is a rather hacky way of doing this. With my example, you are notified of a change instead of checking every so often.

Answer (score -2):

This might not be a very specific solution, but you may be able to apply it.

The way I understand it, is that you need to break out of the timer under a specific condition.

try to put a while loop around your sleep and make it sleep for a second

Set the condition as a bool on your func

```
while (condition_to_sleep)
{
    time.Sleep(1000);
}
```

This way you can break out of the timer when you need to

Hope this help :)

Comment: This is the wrong way to handle concurrency in any language. Downvote

Comment: This is not C. Your code won't compile because (1) there is no such thing as while and (2) your braces aren't on the same line.